# Shared state between CloudService instances

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

Im creating a multiplayer game where one player hosts a game session and where others can join that session. The problem im having is how to make sure all players within a session has access to the current game state no matter what cloudservice instance theyve ended up connecting to.

Since this state has to be read pretty frequently, i dont want to put it in a database or storage since i want the fastest possible access time. Right now, its just a list of game sessions in memory within each instance. My first idea was to use the Azure cache functionality but as of this moment, its only available for cloudservice instances of the size Small and up, whereas my instances are extra small ones.

Is it possible to make sure that all joining players end up in the same instance as the hosting player by looking up what instance the hosting player created his game session and then get the endpoint for that instance and pass it back to the joining players to be used throughout the game session?

Or is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Dedicated Cache and paying for Small instances is by far a better approach then to try doing the near-impossible task of trying to bring affinity to a load-balanced environment and also forcing a super bad architecture in place of a good one.

If cost is a concern, I suggest applying for Microsoft's Bizspark program that provides for 2 small instance for free per month.

http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/

Comment: Great suggestion about Bizspark. Yes money is a concern. Also, i got the idea that being able to have more but cheaper instances instead of a few but more flexible in terms of features will allow for more simultaneous connections? How would the solution scale with an increased number of users in that scenario?

Comment: having more and cheaper instances is usually OK as long as those instances are Small or better.  Exrta-Small instances are not production (or anything serious) ready.   They have 5% of the bandwidth, 50% of the RAM, and a /non-dedicated/ CPU.  They're mostly good for dev work.